# Design pattern choice for application

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

I am starting a project consisting of a few solvers (all solving the same type of equation) of partial differential equation for industrial purposes. The application is supposed to have GUI (separated from computational code) and DLLs with different solvers. The aim is to achieve the extensibility in order to create new better solvers and add them to the solver list as plugins. Different solvers require sets of different parameters. What kind of design patter should I consider?

Comment: Define an interface and access your solvers through this interface, then you are free to (ex-)change the implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Strategy Pattern seems like a good fit.
Gist of it, is to implement an interface which all your solvers would implement.

Then the class which consists of the solvers would contains a List where you can insert/remove solvers at run time.

This way you are encapsulating what changes (i.e the solver)

More info about strategy pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Gang of Four design patterns, but I'd recommend a few things based on what I know about finite element methods:

1. Start with an interface (all pure virtual functions) for solvers.
2. Use dependency injection and a factory to instantiate the solver implementation based on solution type.
3. Externalize parameters into a map for ease and flexibility.
4. Write custom validators for each solution type to guarantee that you have the proper input before you begin that hard work of assembling and solving the equations.